# SDL2 with mingw-w64 - linker finds libSDL2.a but throws "undefined reference" errors

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, mingw-w64

Even though `libSDL2.a` is, according to `-Xlinker --verbose`, recognized (and is used) by the linker, every single SDL function that I use is reported as "undefined reference" by `ld.exe`. Here's the linker command line that I invoke:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -L./Client/deps/SDL2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lgdi32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 ./Client/deps/gl3w/obj/windows/x86_64/release/gl3w.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVGLObjects.cpp.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVRenderer.cpp.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVWorldObjects.cpp.o
./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/main.cpp.o -o ./Client/build/output/exe/windows/x86_64/dev/GemVerse.exe
```

As you can see, I use the correct library version (`x86_64` libraries, `x86_64` compiler). `nm` finds all the functions, so the static library files are perfectly fine. By the way, I don't use `SDL_main`, therefore it'sn't on the list.

So, why is `ld` not finding the SDL functions?

Comment: It seems you didn't copy the output/list etc.? By the way, why are you linking `SDL2main` if you don't use `SDL_main`?

Comment: Libraries needs to be specified after object files (or other libraries) using them, not before.

Comment: Also you probably need to add `-lmingw32` before other libraries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's not related, and the code runs fine without it (if I remove SDL mentions)

Comment: @VladislavToncharov Yeah, but you need it if you use SDL2. Do what keltar suggested, then see if it works with and without `-lmingw32`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I included that in an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Keltar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126914/sdl2-with-mingw-w64-linker-finds-libsdl2-a-but-throws-undefined-reference-er#comment100779948_57126914) and [HolyBlackCat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126914/sdl2-with-mingw-w64-linker-finds-libsdl2-a-but-throws-undefined-reference-er#comment100786515_57126914), I put the static libraries after the object files and added some more libraries (as well as removed `-lSDLmain`), the list of libraries becoming:

```
-lSDL2 -lgdi32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lmingw32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lversion -lSetupAPI
```

So the final command line is:

```bsh
PS> 86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -L./Client/deps/SDL2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib ./Client/deps/gl3w/obj/windows/x86_64/release/gl3w.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVGLObjects.cpp.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVRenderer.cpp.o ./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/GVWorldObjects.cpp.o
./Client/build/output/o/windows/x86_64/dev/main.cpp.o -lSDL2 -lgdi32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lmingw32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lversion -lSetupAPI -o ./Client/build/output/exe/windows/x86_64/dev/GemVerse.exe
```